# Perl - Unexptected behaviour with Regex in Array

Tags: regex, arrays, perl, filter

I'm trying to match lines that have

```
"/foldera/folderb/folderc/folderd/file.ext@@/main" + "/" + ANY_NUMBER:
```

so for example:

```
(.+)(main)(.\d)
```

The lines:

```
/foldera/folderb/folderc/folderd/file.ext@@/main
/foldera/folderb/folderc/folderd/file.ext@@/main/0
/foldera/folderb/folderc/folderd/file.ext@@/main/1
/foldera/folderb/folderc/folderd/file.ext@@/main/2
/foldera/folderb/folderc/folderd/file.ext@@/main/3
/foldera/folderb/folderc/folderd/file.ext@@/main/4
/foldera/folderb/folderc/folderd/file.ext@@/main/5 (RLT-abcde, BLD-abcde, DEV-abcde)
/foldera/folderb/folderc/folderx/file12.ext@@/main/0
/foldera/folderb/folderc/folderx/file12.ext@@/main/1
/foldera/folderb/folderc/folderx/file12.ext@@/main/2
/foldera/folderb/folderc/folderx/file12.ext@@/main/3
/foldera/folderb/folderc/folderx/file12.ext@@/main/4
/foldera/folderb/folderc/folderx/file12.ext@@/main/5
/foldera/folderb/folderc/folderx/file12.ext@@/main/6 (RLS-abcde-5.0, RLS-abcde-4.1)
```

While my regex matches the desired lines (I checked it at http://www.regexe.com/), in my Perl program it does not match

```
/foldera/folderb/folderc/folderd/file.ext@@/main
```

but it does match:

```
/foldera/folderb/folderc/folderd/file.ext@@/main/5 (RLT-abcde, BLD-abcde, DEV-abcde)
```

Here is the code:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @file_list = `find /folder -type f -name '*.ext'|xargs cleartool lsvtree -all`;

foreach my $file(@file_list){

  if ($file=~m/(.+)(main)(.\d)/g){ 
   print $file;
  }
}
```

I'm pretty sure that I'm making a stupid mistake **somewhere**, but I just can't see it!

Thank you in advance for your advice.

P.S. I tried it under Perl 5.8 an Perl 5.18 with the same results, OS is Solaris.

Comment: You should try out the `File::Find` module.

Comment: It seems the regex matches what you want - since you say it must have `ANY_NUMBER` after `main/` and your not-matched line does not have `main/ANY_NUMBER` ...

Comment: True, but I had to use the proprietary "cleartool" command anyway, so I quickly piped it together with the find-command. Will look at File::Find, tough.

Comment: @ring0: It prints /foldera/folderb/folderc/folderd/file.ext@@/main/5 (RLT-abcde, BLD-abcde, DEV-abcde)
 but I need /foldera/folderb/folderc/folderd/file.ext@@/main/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
print $file;
```

to:

```
print "$MATCH\n";
```

so you only print the part of the line that was matched by the regexp.

You should also change `\d` to `\d+`, to allow for numbers with more than one digit.

Comment: When I do that, it filters out /foldera/folderb/folderc/folderx/file12.ext@@/main/6 (RLS-abcde-5.0, RLS-abcde-4.1)
 completely but I want /foldera/folderb/folderc/folderx/file12.ext@@/main/6

Comment: The problem is that you're printing the whole line, not just that part that what was matched by the regexp.

Comment: Updated the answer now that I understand the question.

Comment: Yes, of course! You are right! I could slap my self for that! Thank you!! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just after a quick look

*/foldera/folderb/folderc/folderd/file.ext@@/main*

Has no number at the end. And \d requires the number ;-)

You may also find this site usefull: http://regexpal.com/

Comment: That behavior is desired, I don't want /foldera/folderb/folderc/folderd/file.ext@@/main, as I wrote above.

Answer (score 0):

I think is not matching your line because your regex is explicitly looking for a digit at the end

Try changing your regex to be:  (Note the curley brackets at the end)

(.+)(main)(.\d){0,1}

Or personally I would write it like this:

(.*?)main(\/\d*){0,1}

Hope this helps!

Comment: He doesn't want the lines with no number.